# setting timeout for cxf rest client in tomee

Tags: jakarta-ee, cxf, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I wish to set the ReceiveTimeout property at application level for all jax-rs requests in Tomee. I am unable to find any documentation specific to setting the property other than at a low level in code:

```
client.property("http.receive.timeout", "1000");
```

For setting an interceptor, Tomee documentation suggests:

1. set openejb-jar
2. set resources.xml

as below.

Any idea how the setting of client properties can be achieved?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openejb-jar>
 <pojo-deployment class-name="jaxrs-application">
   <properties>
     # optional but requires to skip scanned providers if set to true
     cxf.jaxrs.skip-provider-scanning = true
     # list of providers we want
     cxf.jaxrs.providers = johnzon,org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.EJBAccessExceptionMapper
   </properties>
 </pojo-deployment>
</openejb-jar>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
 <Service id="johnzon" class-name="org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.ConfigurableJohnzonProvider">
   # 1M
   maxSize = 1048576
   bufferSize = 1048576

   # ordered attributes
   attributeOrder = $order

   # Additional types to ignore
   ignores = org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody
 </Service>

 <Service id="order" class-name="com.company.MyAttributeSorter" />

</resources>
```